# how to return a formula from user form

Tags: textbox, formula, userform

I am trying to multiply value in Textbox1 X Textbox2 using commandbotton1, so for example if Textbox1 = 3 and TextBox2 = 2.5
I would like to see result in textBox3 as formula including values from TextBox1&2 =3x2.5
i don't want to see result as value 7

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Me.TextBox3 = Me.TextBox1 * Me.TextBox2

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this ?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  With Me
    .TextBox3.Value = "=" & .TextBox1.Value & " * " & .TextBox2.Value
  End With
End Sub
```